# Proof of ideals in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that every ideal $I$ in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is finitely generated as follows. Let $I_0=I\cap\mathbf{Z}$ and let $I_1=\{b\in\mathbf{Z}:a+b\sqrt{d}\in I \ \text{for some} \ a\in\mathbf{Z}\}$.

(a) Prove that $I_0$ and $I_1$ are ideals in $\mathbf{Z}$. Therefore, $I_0=(r_0)$ and $I_1=(r_1)$ for some $r_i\in\mathbf{Z}$.

My attempt: Let $r_0\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $s\in I_0$. Then $s=a^2-b^2d=(a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d})\in I $ and $\mathbf{Z}$.

Then $r_0s=r_0(a^2-b^2d)=r_0a^2-r_0b^2d\in I\cap\mathbf{Z}$ is non zero since $(a,b)\neq(0,0)\in I$. Hence $I_0=(r_0)$

Now let $r_1\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $k\in I$. So there is an $a_1\in\mathbf{Z}$ s.t. $k=a_1+b\sqrt{d}$.

Then $r_1k=r_1(a_1+b\sqrt{d})=r_1a_1+r_1b\sqrt{d}\in I_1$. Hence $I_1=(r_1)$.

(b) Prove that $I_0\subseteq I_1$.

I assume show that $(r_0)\subseteq (r_1)$? Not sure how to go about this.

(c) By definition of $I_1$ there exists $a_1\in\mathbf{Z}$ s.t. $a_1+r_1\sqrt{d}$ is in $I$. Prove that $I$ is ideal generated by $r_0$ and $a_1+r_1\sqrt{d}$.

Lost on this too since it follows from (a) and (b).

Comment: I don't think you're trying (a) in the right way.  What is r_0?  It looks like you're saying that for any r_0 in Z, I = (r_0), and that's not true.  To prove I_0 is an ideal, show it's non-empty, and then show that if r_0 and r_1 are in the intersection, then r_0 + r_1 is in the intersection and r_0 * s is in the intersection for every s in Z.

Comment: @CJD Yes my failure to understand (a) is why I'm having a hard time with (b) and (c). To show it is non-empty I can choose an element from $I_0$ such as $0$? Also if $r_0\in I\cap \mathbf{Z}$ how does $r_0$ look like? Do I pick a specific $r_0$?

Comment: You're right that you can pick 0 as a specific element to show it's non-empty.  You don't have to give any kind of specific formula for r_0... there's a theorem that says every ideal in Z can be written as (r_0) for some integer r_0, so the key idea is to prove it's an ideal.  As an example of what elements in I_0 look like, say your ideal I is (2 + 3i).  Then (2+3i)*(2-3i) = 13 is in I and is an integer, so 13 is an example of an element in I_0 for the specific ideal (2+3i).  26, 0, -13, ... would be other examples for this same ideal.

Comment: @CJD So I can just say for $(a+b\sqrt{d})\in I$ then $(a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d})=a^2-b^2d\in I\cap\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: You're right that's a general formula to produce elements in both I and Z.  I don't think that will help you prove I_0 is an ideal in Z though.  For example, to prove I_0 is closed under addition: if a is in I_0 and b is in I_0, then a + b is in I (since a and b are in I), and a+b is in Z (since a and b are in Z), hence a+b is in I_0.

Comment: @CJD Ah yes thank you I have that down. I was trying to figure out the absorption property.